# npm start got SyntaxError: Named export 'stc' not found

Tags: express

i am new to express js, after installation i tried to run  npm start but i got error "SyntaxError: Named export 'stc' not found"

[image]

here is the app.js

```
import createError from 'http-errors';
import express, { json, urlencoded, stc } from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import logger from 'morgan';

import indexRouter from './routes/index.js';
import usersRouter from './routes/users.js';

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(json());
app.use(urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(stc(join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

export default app;
```

what is wrong please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
import express from 'express'
const {json, urlencoded, stc} = express
```

or switch to `CommonJS`